# Weird boot behavior that Ubuntu (kinda) fixes

Tags: boot, ssd, windows-10, gparted, ntfs

I have Windows 10 installed on my SSD. When I try to boot the computer, the loading Windows spinner is (always) stopping after 2 seconds and it freezes my computer.

I found that if I then boot Ubuntu from a USB stick (live preview, not installed) and use the GParted tool to just 'check' the SSD partitions, then next time I boot my computer Windows loads correctly.

But if I restart or shut down the computer, the same cycle happens :(

From what I can gather, Windows is setting a flag on my partitions that stops it from loading correctly, and Ubuntu's 'check' command is setting the correct flags.

My question is if I can make the correct flags to be set permanently by Ubuntu? Or does anyone has any idea what is happening?

Comment: There isn't a `check` option in `parted` so it's not clear to what you are referring. Since it seems that your problem has to do exclusively within the Windows operating system, I'm not sure this is the best place for you to ask.  SuperUser would be able to discuss your problems with Windows

Comment: @Nmath I think the command executed is 'ntfsfix' when selecting 'check'. Ok, I will ask the question in SuperUser, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: In that case, definitely check your support options for Windows. Even though there's an open source driver, NTFS is a proprietary file system from Microsoft for Windows so if there's a problem with the file system it's better to use their tools.

Comment: After more than a year, I figured out the problem. I'm posting here my info, in case this happens to someone else: My boot settings were non-UEFI (CSM). That forced me to use NTFS partitions with MBR. Switching to UEFI boot with FAT32 partitions and GPT fixed the issue.